# What is the best way to setup memcached on CentOS to work with Apache and PHP

Tags: php, linux, memcached

What is the simplest way to install memcached on CentOS for someone new to the world of Linux?  What is the best way to enable it for Apache and PHP

Answer (score 1):

Unless Apache and PHP have some option to utilize memcached for internal workings (of which I am unaware of), you typically don't "enable" it for such apps.  Instead, you would get a [client library](http://www.danga.com/memcached/apis.bml) to use memcached from within your application, then start up memcached on whatever servers you want to provide memory with, then just use the client library API to store and retrieve cached data across multiple servers.

Comment: > Unless Apache and PHP have some option to utilize memcached for
> internal workings (of which I am unaware of), you typically don't
> "enable" it for such apps. You need it to create a bitcoin mining pool.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to find a reilable source of the RPM's needed to install memcached and memcached for PHP.  There is a blog post which addresses this concern:

http://blog.gahooa.com/2009/02/08/update-on-fedora-vs-redhat-enterprise-linux/

We have been using EPEL (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux) for exactly that on RedHat Enterprise 5.3.  I believe it is a stated goal of EPEL to support Centos.

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

Essentially, it is a YUM repository which contains lots of extra packages from Fedora that were compiled for RHEL.  **Super easy to use.**